# PHP Session Data is not transferring from page to page within the same domain of HTTPS environment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working with https://www.thereverendmichael.com/3.0/
with a demo login of demo/demo (username/password). It's just too much code to post it all but I will post the integral parts I am having an issue with. The issue I am having is that for some reason when I attempt an Ajax query to an https page and attempt to set the successful `$_GET` variables as `$_SESSION` variables, they do not transfer over and it returns unauthorized access.

[form.php]

```
<? 
session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Unauthorized access. Redirecting to login page...");
            window.location="https://www.thereverendmichael.com/3.0/index.php";
        </script>
    </head>
</html> 
<? } ?>
```

[index.php]

```js
 $("#login-submit").click(function(){
   $("#login-form").trigger("submit");
 });
 $("#login-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "https://www.thereverendmichael.com/3.0/login.php",
   data: $("#login-form").serialize(),
   cache: true,
   AllowGet: true,
   success: function(data) 
   {
    switch(data)
     {
      case "1":
       alert("Admin login successful. Redirecting...");
       window.location = "https://www.thereverendmichael.com/console/admin.php";
       break;
      case "2":
       alert("Login successful. Redirecting...");
       window.location = "https://www.thereverendmichael.com/3.0/form.php";
       break;
      case "3":
       alert("Username does not match account records. Please try again.");
       break;
      case "4":
       alert("Password does not match account records. Please try again.");
       break;
     }
   }
  });
 });
```

[login.php]

```php
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    $conn = mysql_connect("107.180.20.91", "redphyre", "Qazplm10!") or die(mysql_error());
    $conn = mysql_select_db("mikenbrenda", $conn);

    $user = $_GET['username'];
    $pass = md5($_GET['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT username,password,admin FROM users WHERE username = '$user'";

    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    class SessionManager
    {
       static function sessionStart($name, $limit = 0, $path = '/', $domain = null, $secure = null)
       {
          // Set the cookie name before we start.
          session_name($name . '_Session');

          // Set the domain to default to the current domain.
          $domain = isset($domain) ? $domain : isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

          // Set the default secure value to whether the site is being accessed with SSL
          $https = isset($secure) ? $secure : isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']);

          // Set the cookie settings and start the session
          session_set_cookie_params($limit, $path, $domain, $secure, true);
          session_start();
       }
    }

    if ($row[0] == $user && $pass == $row[1]) {
        SessionManager::sessionStart('login', 0, '/', 'www.thereverendmichael.com', true);
        $_SESSION['id'] = $user;
        if ($row[2] == "1") {
            $_SESSION['admin'] = $row[2];
            setcookie("admin", $row[2]);
            echo "1";
        }
        else {
            echo "2";
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($row[0] != $user) {
            echo "3";
        }
        if ($row[1] != $pass) {
            echo "4";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you have session_start in all the pages at the top most part of your scripts/files?

Comment: login_Session is the session name, not a session variable, so your form.php page is failing to find that variable.

Comment: @FunkDoc yup you're absolutely right about that, idk why I did that but when I change it to just "id", it still doesn't work. Updated on site.

Comment: can you print_r($_SESSION) on the form.php page? what does it look like? Also, unrelated you should not be using mysql_query anymore. especially for login scripts. Use prepared statements of PDO or mysqli.

Comment: You're also setting a `$https` variable but using `$secure` instead inside your `sessionStart()` method

Comment: @unixmiah that actually fixed it!

Comment: @WillardSolutions thank you for that catch, it's an in-progress haha

Comment: @FunkDoc it looks like it was due to not having `session_start()` on the top of each page.

Comment: @MatthewWalker Im glad you got it fixed =)

Comment: @FunkDoc I can't seem to grasp PDO, idk why